# how do i remove the first characters of a string [python]

Tags: python, string, replace

thanks to answers on this site I now know that you can remove the last characters of a string by string[:-1] which was really helpfull, however I need to be able to remove the first aswell and as far as I understand this technique it is not possible. so are there other ways to remove parts of strings without replacing spesific letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean "it is not possible"?  :)

It is perfectly possible with [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> mystr = 'abcde'
>>> mystr[1:] # Remove the first
'bcde'
>>> mystr[1:-1] # Remove the first and the last
'bcd'
>>> mystr[2:-2] # Remove the first two and the last two
'c'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`string[1:]`

You may need to read some documentation. :)